# how to fake url detection by php

Tags: php, url, curl, artificial-intelligence

im working on a script for indexing and downloading whole website by user sent url

for example when a user submit a domain like http://example.com then i will copy all links in index page and go for download the its inside links and start from first.....

i do this part with curl and regular expression to download and extract the links

however 
some yellow websites are making fake urls for example if you go to http://example.com?page=12 it have some links to http://example.com?page=12&id=10 or http://example.com?page=13 and etc..
this will make a loop and the script cant complete the site downloading

is there any way to detect these kind of pages!?

p.s.: i think google and yahoo and some other search engines face this kind of problem too but their database are clear and on searches thay dont show these kind of data....

Comment: What do you mean by "fake URL"?

Comment: as i said in 4th section fake urls are a pages that only linked to some other pages and make a loop like some warez websites

Comment: If it actually links to another page then it is not fake. If you find that the content is redundant then index the content by a hash or try to find what % difference is acceptable to count as a distinct resource. You might also look for the canonical URL in the link element.

Comment: what is your idea about md5 , i mean i make md5 of all page content in database and if i found duplicated md5 it will be a duplicated page!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pages may use GET variables and be perfectly valid (like as you've mentioned here, ?page=12 and ?page=13 may be acceptable). So what I believe you're actually looking for here is a **unique** page.

It's not possible however to detect these straight from their URL. ?page=12 may point to exactly the same thing as ?page=12&id=1 does; they may not. The only way to detect one of these is to download it, compare the download to pages you've already got, and as a result find out if it really is one you haven't seen yet. If you have seen it before, don't crawl its links.

*Minor side note here: Make sure you block websites from a different domain, otherwise you may accidentally start crawling the whole web :)*

Comment: yes as i got you think some human control is required and block fake urls?! how ever i really like to know what is search engines solution for these kind of pages!!

Comment: Search engines have a lot of storage space, but they too work in this way. They store documents seperate from the URL they were found at and search for unique documents (which are then referenced by their 'DocID' or 'DocumentID').